# Is TRIM disabled even with Windows Soft RAID 1 (Windows Dynamic Disks)

Tags: windows, ssd, raid-1

I am looking to build a Windows 2008 Server and wanted to use a RAID SSD array, either via SATAIII or PCIe.

Everything I've seen that RAID does not allow TRIM commands to be passed to the SSD, except for certain Intel Drives and chipsets.

Is this also the case when using Windows Dynamic Disks? Can anybody clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how the disk is configured in Windows, if it's an SSD in hardware RAID, you'll get no TRIM (unless on the new chipset as you identify).

It would seem that soft-RAID will let you TRIM: http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=85391